# Ensure nav bar is full width

Tags: html, css

Right now I'm building a nav bar and I can't seem to get it to reach the full width of the page. I tried setting margin to `0 auto` but that did not work. Here is a screenshot and current CSS and Mockup.

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there is some margin around the nav bar I don't want there anymore.

CSS:

```
 .topbar {
  background-color: $topbar-background-color;
  height: $topbar-height;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="topbar">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, class: "button" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class: "button" %>
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "button" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/38ubnfz7/

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Do you mean the whitespace to the left of the dark nav bar? It looks like there's some padding on the parent container or somewhere up the tree.

Comment: did you check and see if the style of the body has margin: 0?

Comment: Yea, other than the body margin that jsfiddle sets that [nav bar is 100% width](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/38ubnfz7/1/)

Comment: if there are no other parent classes then change the padding and margin of html and body to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is top and bottom margin comes after we set body margin:0; it because of the p element by default get -webkit-margin-before: 1em; -webkit-margin-after: 1em;

SO you need to set the .topbar p{margin:0;} [UPDATE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/38ubnfz7/3/)
I just add a red border on html, body section so that it will be clear to everyone there is no margin between topbar and the body section.

Thanks.

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
 border:1px solid red;/* just make this border for the body to make sure there is no margin between body and the topnav div */
}
.topbar {
  background-color: rgb(68,68,68);
  height: 50px;
 padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
}
.topbar p{
margin:0;
background-color:lightblue;
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <p>
  sign out
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting margin, keep in mind that using shorthand notation (ie. `margin: auto 0`) will apply the first argument to the top and bottom, and the second to right and left. This is this same as:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
```

For whatever reason, css properties tend to travel clockwise.

Now, without a fiddle we cannot know for sure, but there's a good chance that the margin is being inherited from its parent (with the right/left property set to `auto`). See if simply using `margin: 0` fixes it. If not, open up dev tools and see if there's any margin or padding from the parent being applied. Chrome has a handy illustration:

[image: An HTML div nested within parent container with padding applied.]

Follow the path up the node chain until you find the guilty container.

You may also want to specify zero margin or padding for the

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In regard to the fiddle, the nav bar's parent element is the body and it has a margin applied to it by default, so you need to deal with that.

```
body {
   margin:0;
}
```

In whatever situation you are using this nav bar, you will need to take into consideration its parent elements and how they impact its layout.

Comment: that's more a comment really, to which you have enough rep for; can you not provide them with a solution?